# Card counting functionality react native

Tags: react-native, cart

I am trying to make an e-commerce app and everything working only the cart icon counts not updating when the user adds an item to cart.

Here is my main page where i am calling component:

```
<Header headerTitle={this.state.wineD.name} lefticonType={'back'} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Here is component code:

```
componentDidMount(){
  //API code here and updating response count in state.
  if(response.data.success){
    this.setState({
        cartItems: (response.data.data.cart.items != '' && (response.data.data.cart.items).length > 0)?
        (response.data.data.cart.items).length : 0
    })
    this.props.changeLoaderStatus();
   }
}

<FlatHeader
        leftIcon={<Icon name={leftIcon} size={20} color="#FFF" />}
        leftIconHandler={() => {
          (this.props.lefticonType == 'bars' ?
          this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
          : goBack())
        }}
        centerContent={
                    <View style={{width: width*0.7,alignItems:'center'}}>
                        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ color: '#FFF',fontSize:22,fontWeight:'bold' }}>{this.props.headerTitle}</Text>
                    </View>
                }
        rightIcon={<Group><Icon name="shopping-cart" size={20} color="#FFF" />
        <View style={{width:16,height:16,borderRadius:8,backgroundColor:'red',justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',marginBottom:14}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:10,color:'#fff',fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.cartItems}</Text></View></Group>}
        rightIconHandler={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Cart')}
        large
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#d7b655' }}
      />
```

This is the screen where from other component updating the cart

[image]

Anyone have solution please share here.

Comment: `componentDidMount()` is called just once, when the component is mounted. Do you mean you are mounting a different component every time the user add something to cart? Isn't, instead, your header always visible and, so, the component still mounted?

Comment: I just updated my code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your problem, you may need to modify `this.setState` in this way:

```
componentDidMount(){
  //API code here and updating response count in state.
  if(response.data.success){
    this.setState({
        cartItems: (response.data.data.cart.items != '' && (response.data.data.cart.items).length > 0)?
        (response.data.data.cart.items).length : 0
    },()=>{
this.props.changeLoaderStatus(); }) } }
```

try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Did you try my suggested change?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked same so I pass props from parent screen.